# SQL : Extract distinct value

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with two col's

```
EmpID  Beneifts
1       A
1       B
2       A
3       A
3       c
4       A
```

my expected output is just that empId with only benefits A

```
EmpID   Benefits
2        A
4        A
```

please help me with a query.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [ask]. Remember **SO is not a free code service!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row of same EmpID doesn't have any benefit but 'A':

```
select *
from tablename t1
where t1.Benefits = 'A'
  and not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.EmpID = t1.EmpID
                    and t2.Benefits <> 'A')
```

Or, do a `GROUP BY`:

```
select EmpID
from tablename
group by EmpID
having min(Benefits) = 'A'
   and max(Benefits) = 'A'
```

Comment: why min/max on the second one? `where benefits='a' having count(benefits) = 1`

Comment: @MarcB that is not enough, 'b' and any other value will be returned too

Comment: @MarcB, could have had count distinct benefits too.